# Should I use requestanimationframe or setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am testing performance in my JavaScript application, a game using canvas. One problem I have is *major* fluctuations with FPS: going from 60 to 2 in ms.

[image]

As you can see, there are major spikes. It is not due to painting, scripting, rendering, or loading. I think it is because requestAnimationFrame doesn't assign a set FPS rate and it might be too flexible? Should I use setTimeout? Is it usually more reliable in these cases because it forces the application to run in only one set FPS rate?

Comment: What kind of work are you doing in the RAF callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance is always about specifics.  Without more information on your app, (e.g. the specific code that renders your app ).  It is hard to say how you should structure your code.

Generally, you should always use requestAnimationFrame.  *Especially* for rendering.

Optionally store the delta time and multiply your animation attributes by that delta.  This will create a smooth animation when the frame rate is not consistent.

I've also found random frame rate changes are usually related to garbage collection.  Perhaps do some memory profiling to find if there are places you can avoid recreating objects each frame.

`requestAnimationFrame` is superior to `setTimeout` in nearly every way.  It won't run as a background tab.  It saves battery.  It gives the browser more information about the type of app you are developing, and this lets the given browser make many safe performance increasing assumptions.

I highly recommend watching this talk by [Nat Duca on browser performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAzhayTnhEI).